# Setting speed of effects

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

There are some effects in osx. For example minimize effect, fullscreen effect, slide effect when changing desktop. But I think these effects taking too long time. For example I'm pushing to CMD+TAB and selecting a full screen application then desktop is sliding about 500 milliseconds. This is slow for me. I want to decrease this time to 100 millisecond. It is time waste and enervator. Can I change time for effects.

I'm using linux in other computer and I can change effect times for compiz. I think there must be same thing in OSX too. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to change the animation speed, but you can change the animation as follows;

System Preferences> Accessibility> Display> Reduce Motion.

Maybe it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This didn't solve my problem but this very good option. Thanks